# Already updated my pip, still failed to add circle as a module

Tags: python, class, pip, geometry, translate

1. I have been searching for different methods for using a class method to create circles. At first, I was able to print 'c1', however, after updating my python, it said is not defined which confuses me.

```
def __int__(x0, y0, r):
          self.x0 = x0
          self.y0 = y0
          self.r = r

    # create a unit circle centered at (0,0)
        c1 = Circle(0, 0, 1)
    
    # create a circle of radius 3 centered at (0,0)
        c2 = Circle(0, 0, 3)
    
    # create a unit circle centered at (2, 5)
        c3 = Circle(2, 5, 1)

    # create a circle of radius 3 centered at (4, 2)
        c4 = Circle(3, 4, 2)

    print (c1)
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

2. 

```
    from circle.Circle import move

    c1_xdelta = 4
    c1_ydelta = 5

    for i in range(1, 20):
        if i%10 == 0:
            c1.move(c1_xdelta, c1_ydelta)

    from circle.Circle import move
        c1_xdelta = 4
        c1_ydelta = 5

    for i in range(1, 20):
       if i%10 == 0:
           c1.move(c1_xdelta, c1_ydelta)

    from circle.Circle import move
         c1_xdelta = 4
         c1_ydelta = 5

    for i in range(1, 20):
       if i%10 == 0:
         c1.move(c1_xdelta, c1_ydelta)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent 
       call last)
     ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7076/1685247526.py in <module>
         ----> 1 from circle.Circle import move
      2 c1_xdelta = 4
      3 c1_ydelta = 5
      4 
      5 for i in range(1, 20):
 
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'circle'
```

Is there any method that I can solve it or any recommended websites for such programming functions? Thank you.

Comment: You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: And format the code properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things wrong here. First off a class doesn't take in any arguments, so instead of

```
class Circle(object):
```

it would just be

```
class circle
```

secondly you are using one underscore for `__init__`, so it'd be

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(x0, y0, r):
```

also you aren't setting the declared variables to anything, it needs to be this

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(x0, y0, r):
        self.x0 = x0 
        self.y0 = y0 
        self.r = r
```

it's also best not to use capitals for variable names, so change R to r

you've also indented the c1, c2, c3 and c4 variables to be inside the class, it needs to be this

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(x0, y0, r):
        self.x0 = x0 
        self.y0 = y0 
        self.r = r

c1 = Circle(0, 0, 1)
c2 = Circle(0, 0, 3)
c3 = Circle(2, 5, 1)
c4 = Circle(3, 4, 2)
```

now you can print out c1. But c1 will just print out something like `<__main__.circle object at 0x000001F89906A0A0>` because you're printing the object itself. If you want to print a specific value you use the . operator, so it'd be

```
print(c1.x0)
```

that'd print the `x0` variable

if you want to print them all you could use

```
print(c1.x0, c1.y0, c1.r)
```

is this something along the lines of what you're going for?

```
class circle:
    def __init__(self, x0, y0, r):
        self.x0 = x0
        self.y0 = y0
        self.r = r

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.x0 += x
        self.y0 += y

c1 = circle(0, 0, 1)

c1_xdelta = 4
c1_ydelta = 5

for i in range(1, 20):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        c1.move(c1_xdelta, c1_ydelta)

print(c1.x0, c1.y0)
```

Comment: Thanksss Lewis, but I am still having problems with it as it says 'Circle() takes no arguments.' and actually I have already updated my pip but I still could not install the 'circle' module

Comment: Can you post all of your code please? The formatting is also very difficult to read

Comment: You only use import if the class is located in another file to the rest of the program. Also, You don't have to write from circle.Circle import move, you just have to write from "the name of the file the circle class is created in" import *, this will import everything from the file that the circle class is created in. You only have to write this once at the top of your program

Comment: I've updated my comment with some code that should be what you're looking for

Comment: Oh I didnt noticed the import part. Thank you !!!

Comment: I've edited my original comment to add some code that I think is what you're trying to do. It's added to the bottom of my original answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71279419/10462963

Comment: No worries man, We were all there at some point! Derek Banas has a great series on Python on YouTube, The series not the hours long video. I think you can mark the question as answered now mate, Best of luck in the future!